# wedge on an exterior algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, ideals, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit and $I \subseteq A$ an ideal of $A$. Prove that with $a,b,c \in I$ we have $$a(b\wedge c) = a \wedge (bc) = (bc) \wedge a $$

Here's what I thought: I know that $b\wedge c$ is the image of the pair $(b,c)$ under the morphism $fg$:
$$ I^2 \xrightarrow{g} I^{\otimes2} \xrightarrow{f} \Lambda^2I $$
So if I take $a(b\wedge c) = a\cdot fg(b,c) = a\cdot f(b \otimes c) = f(ab \otimes c) = f(a \otimes bc ) = a \wedge bc$. This could be a possible solution? Any other method for proving that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to deconvolute into $g$ as the penultimate step.

Comment: @JMP $f(ab\otimes c) = f( a \otimes bc) = f( a \otimes b)\cdot c = fg(a.b)\cdot c$, and the solution is right and complete?

Comment: You can just say $f(a\otimes bc)=fg(a,bc)=a\wedge bc$.

Comment: @JMP I imagine that the last part of the equation of the exercise is true because inside the tensor product I can switch $a,b,c$ to right or left without any problem respecting the multiplication order right?

Comment: Because $a,b,c \in I\subset A$, and $A$ is a commutative ring ($ab=ba$).